# choosing 3D library / platform for mobile and Desktop application

Tags: mobile, 3d, cross-platform, desktop-application, desktop

I want to build an application for mobile (ios,android) and Desktop (Windows) or Web.

The application will look like this: a 3D object which the user can play with the camera perspective around it and some menus.

What I need is to **manipulate a 3D Object** like torus or tube. by manipulate I mean: change materials and edit the object like a polygon. of course I also need menus and communication to a server.

*Optional: I am not sure if I need to load 3D model from a file.

What I don't understand is should I look for all in one solution or combine a cross platform framework with other libraries? Are Game engine suitable for this task?

My options so far:

1. Use Three.js with PhoneGap and write in java script
2. Use OGRE and write in C++ with some cross-platform framework that allow me to write in C++.

I never developed for mobile and I wonder about those cross-platform frameworks: does the application's size is big? does the application runs well? which obstacles should i have comparing writing separate applications for each platform?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look at [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html) .